# get external data excel 2016

Tags: excel, import, text-files

Have the "Get external data" option from the data ribbon been removed in Excel 2016? I cannot find it, I can only see the "Get Data" option. But if I use that and select a text file I do not get the headers and the other options like I would have if I was to use the New workbook - select text file.

Comment: Should be on [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click the ribbon and click on `customize the ribbon`
2. Next select main tabs from the `choose commands from` drop down box
3. Expand `Data` and `Add` the options you need

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csNGk.jpg)

Comment: Ahh, there it was. Thanks!